# Storing Bearer Tokens

Tags: laravel, bearer-token

I have successfully managed to create registration and login API routes in Laravel where a bearer token is issued when the user successfully logs in. The user may then use said bearer token to access his/her information and logout and so the user and logout routes are protected by authorization header middleware. For now I have tested these APIs using postman. For the actual implementation, when a user successfully logs in - where should the bearer token be stored (cookies perhaps?) in order for the user's session to pass the bearer token and access other pages with his/her information? Moreover how could a remember me method be implemented? and should refresh tokens be implemented? In order to eliminate cases where the user is logged out during a session if the token expires.

Tia!!

Comment: Are you using another solution (react, angular) for the front ? if you're using laravel's blade for the front, dont use the `Bearer token` solution, use a state-full one with session and cookies.

Comment: @N69S As re the front-end I'm still unsure what to use, perhaps I should still use a Laravel framework since I'm accustomed to it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to implement refresh tokens.
And yes it's good option to use the cookie for storing the token and the date of expirations. Once it's expired you have to call the refresh token endpoint and to update the token in the cookie.

About 'remember me' method. As long as you are not cleaning the cookie when the user leave the page you are kind of implementing this method and it will keep the user logged in untile the refresh token is no longer available.

Comment: Hi Denis thank you for your comment, so as a procedure it would be something as follows;
1. Log in and give the user a token which is stored in the cookies
2. Retrieve token from the cookies and use it to access personal information
3. If token expires, re-assign new token
4. If remember me is checked token is not deleted when the user leaves the page else it is deleted

I am using the Laravel framework to implement this, are there ways to know if the user is active during a session or not for example? to implement refresh tokens for example

Comment: About implementing the refresh token. You will store the access token, the date when it expires and the refresh token into cookie. When the access token expires you will need to create a new request to the backend authenticate endpoint but with your refresh token and it will return new (access_tokem, expires_in, refresh_token).
Once you have them you will update the cookie.

Comment: Something just come to my mind. Probably if you have remember me and if it's off then I guess do not want to use the refresh token but to redirect to login page.

Comment: Thanks once again Denis, what does the refresh_token parameter actually refer to? Additionally I am considering issuing auth_token which is stored in the users' cookies for approx a month. That way I eliminate the use of remember me since users get a substantial amount of time to access their information and they refresh their token once a month. Not sure of security threats though.

Comment: So your authentication endpoint should work at least with these two types of authentication:
1. Username and password
2. Refresh token

When you don't have any information about this client you are going to redirect him to login page where he will put username and password and the response will be {access_token, expires_in, refresh_token}

But when you already have the refresh_token in the cookie but accsee_token already expired you can request the authentication endpoint with the refresh_token and you will expect the same response as in the first case. Is it clear?

Comment: Hi Denis, authentication is currently being done using username and password. Upon first login a token is being issued which is stored in a users/tokens table and in a cookie together with the expiration date. When attempting to login or access the user's personal information the cookie can be retrieved and the token checked for validity in the users/tokens table. In order to eliminate refresh tokens/remember me tokens I planned on issuing tokens with a longer expiration date thus eliminating the need to continuously re-issue tokens. Does my method make sense?

Comment: The idea of having a low life is to increase security because if these tokens have a longer life they can be very easily stolen and then used by someone else. May kindly ask you to vote if some of my questions give you answers to what you are searching for, thanks! Keep asking if it's not clear